# Partial derivative with two sets of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

My question is about Example 1 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/2.-partial-derivatives/part-c-lagrange-multipliers-and-constrained-differentials/session-43-clearer-notation/MIT18_02SC_MNotes_n1_2.pdf). The authors discuss the function
$$w=x^2+y^2+z^2 $$
which is the squared distance from the origin, subject to the constraint
$$z=x^2+y^2 $$
which means that the point is restricted to this paraboloid. $w$ can be expressed as a function of two variables in two different ways:

1. $w(x,y)=x^2+y^2+(x^2+y^2)^2$, in which case $\partial w/\partial x=2x+4x(x^2+y^2)$.
2. $w(x,z)=z+z^2$, in which case the authors claim that $\partial w/\partial x=0$.

I'm skeptic about the $w(x,z)$ case: Fixing $z=1$ restricts us to the circle $\mathcal{C}=\{x^2+y^2=1,z=1$}. If one wants to differentiate $w$ w.r.t. $x$ at the point $P=(1,0,1)$ one needs to evaluate $w$ at points with $x=1+\Delta x$. Isn't this impossible to do with $\Delta x>0$? After all, $P$ is the point with the largest $x$ value on the circle $\mathcal{C}$. Shouldn't the correct result be about a one-sided derivative, such as
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0^-} \frac{w(1+\Delta x,1)-w(P)}{\Delta x}=0 ?$$

On the other hand $w(x,z)$ doesn't appear to depend on $x$ at all, so the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ could be argued to be $0$. Please help me clarify what's going on here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The authers use a very bad notation !

If in 1. the variable $z$ is replaced by $x^2+y^2$, it is better to introduce a new function

$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+(x^2+y^2)^2$.

If in 2. the variable $y$ is replaced by $z-x^2$, it is better to introduce a new function

$g(x,z)=z+z^2$.